# How to authenticate passkey from a Tcl script calling bash?

Tags: bash, authentication, cygwin, tcl, ssh-keys

I have a tcl script that calls a lot of functions from bash including ssh. The part I'm struggling with looks like this:

```
proc connect {where} {
    set bash c:/cygwin/bin/bash
    catch {exec $bash -c "ssh $where"} result
    puts $result
}
connect user@localhost
```

I get the authentication failed message:

```
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied (publickey,password,keyboard-interactive).
```

I can't figure out how to prompt (either showing the console or a tk window, doesn't really matter) the user for the password so the authentication goes through.

The reason I'm using bash to ssh is because eventually I want to connect to a github with the script (need to prompt for a passkey).

Comment: adding -t -t to ssh got rid of the first error, the << for passphrase unfortunately doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
puts -nonewline "enter your passphrase: "
flush stdout
gets stdin passphrase
exec $bash -c "ssh $where" << $passphrase
```

The `<<` argument to `exec` passes the given value to the command on its stdin

If that doesn't work, you'll have to try Expect, or use a key with no passphrase.

Comment: +1 for Expect. Past the very simple stuff, its a great (Tcl) library for automating tasks "as if the script was the user".

Answer (score 0):

One important alternative (which I advise) is to set up a local key-handling agent (e.g., `ssh-agent` or `pageant`) to hold the decrypted key so that your code doesn't need to handle passwords at all. I find that's a much simpler method overall because it stops a lot of code from having to understand anything about passwords (which are harder to handle correctly than you might think…)